# Solving $\frac{dy}{dx}=\cos{x}\cos{y}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I've been trying to solve the following differential equation:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\cos{x}\cos{y}$$
but I can't seem to figure it out. Here are the steps I've taken:

1. Separate the variables onto their own sides of the equation:
   $$\sec y \,dy = \cos x\,dx$$
2. Integrate both sides of the equation:
   $$\ln|\sec y + \tan y| = \sin x + C$$
3. Eliminate natural logarithm on LHS:
   $$|\sec y + \tan y| = Ce^{\sin x}$$

My solution is supposed to be in the form $y=f(x)$. However, now, there's no way to a solution (that I can see). Am I missing some obvious algebra, or did I mess up an earlier step? Thanks!

Comment: what exactly do you mean by solution here cuz usually the function u found is the answer

Comment: Sorry, I clarified the post. My solution is supposed to be in the form $y=f(x)$.

Comment: You can use $\cos^2 y$ expression for $\tan y$ and then solve quadratic equation to find explicit solutions

Comment: What makes you think you have to give $y$ explicitly as a function of $x$? In this case, however, you can rewrite your left-hand side by using some trigonometry knowledge. Try double/half angle formulas after you get a common denominator.

Comment: Why do you think there is a closed form solution?

Comment: There actually is, in this case.

Comment: Hint: $(\sec y + \tan y) (\sec y - \tan y) = \sec^2 y - \tan^2 y = 1$, so you know also $\sec y - \tan y = \frac{1}{C} e^{-\sin x}$.  From this, you should be able to solve for $\tan y$, and then for $y$.

Comment: The quadratic formula is *so* messy. See my hint below. It gets you to the inverse trig function far more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**: $\dfrac{1+\cos\theta}{\sin\theta} = \dfrac{\cos^2(\theta/2)}{\sin(\theta/2)\cos(\theta/2)} = \cot(\theta/2)$.

Now how do we relate $\theta$ and $y$?

Comment: This helped, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Note that there is another less known anti-derivative of $\sec(y)$ than $\ln|\sec y + \tan y|$

Indeed remember $\tan(u)'=1+\tan(u)^2$ and $\operatorname{arctanh}(u)'=\dfrac 1{1-u^2}$

And the half angle formula for $\cos(y)=\dfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$ for $t=\tan(y/2)$

Therefore $\Big(2\operatorname{arctanh}(\tan(y/2))\Big)'=2\times\frac 12\times\dfrac{1+\tan(y/2)^2}{1-\tan(y/2)^2}=\dfrac 1{\cos(y)}=\sec(y)$

And this is LHS is easy to invert (get $y$ in function of $\sin x$).

Answer (score 0):

Following [Bioche's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioche%27s_rules), let $u:=\sin y$.

$$\begin{align}\int\sec y\,dy&=\int\frac{\cos y\,\mathrm dy}{\cos^2y}\\&=\int\frac{\mathrm du}{1-u^2}\\&=\frac12\int\left(\frac1{u+1}-\frac1{u-1}\right)\,\mathrm du\\&=\frac12\left[\ln\left|\frac{u+1}{u-1}\right|\right]\\&=\frac12\left[\ln\frac{1+\sin y}{1-\sin y}\right]\end{align}$$
and (with $C\ge0$)
$$\frac{1+\sin y}{1-\sin y}=Ce^{2\sin x}\iff\sin y=\frac{Ce^{2\sin x}-1}{Ce^{2\sin x}+1}.$$