# Parameterize Grim Reaper Curve by arc length

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, curves, arc-length

I have to solve the next problem for a course at university:

> Parametrise the grim's reaper curve $y = -\ln(\cos x)$ with $x \in \bigl(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\bigr)$ by the arc length using the parametric equation of itself and the fundamental theorem of the local theory of curves.

So I have proceeded to write the equation in a parametric way:
$$
\begin{cases}
x = t \\
y = -\ln(\cos t)
\end{cases}
$$

And I have got the arc length integrating from $0$ to $T$:
$$
S = \ln(\sec t + \tan t)
$$

Now I think I have isolate the $T$ and substitute in the $x,y$ equations, but I think it is not possible? Maybe have I missed an step?

[image: My work]

Thanks in advance

Comment: See my answer to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4850035/solving-fracdydx-cosx-cosy/4850043#4850043).

Comment: Where on Earth (or under the Earth ?) have you seen this curve under this weird name ?Naming it in this way, in particular in the title doesn't bring anything positive !

Comment: Try to write your integral as a function you can invert. Looking on the web you'll see there are ways to integrate sec to have an easily invertible function.

Comment: It is often useful to write $\sin \theta =  \frac{2t}{1+t^2}$, $\cos \theta =  \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$, with $t=\tan \frac{\theta}{2}$.

Comment: You'll also be needing $\sinh u =  \frac{2t}{1-t^2}$, $\cosh u =  \frac{1+t^2}{1-t^2}$, with $t=\tanh \frac{u}{2}$ to finish your calculations.